# How to send an email if a field value is changed

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, development, designer-workflow

I am working on an Issue Tracking List inside SP 2013. And I have a field named `Issue Owner`. I want to create a workflow that should be executed when an issue item is edited and at the same time  the `Issue Owner` field is changed. So is there a way inside the SharePoint designer to specify an If statement which validate if a field value is changed ?

Answer (score 2):

No direct way because SharePoint Designer workflow don't give us Previous values like Event Receivers does.

If you don't want to follow Event Receiver path, then try below workaround

1. You need to have a hidden field in the list (Say Previous Owner).
2. Add logic in you New/Edit form to populate Previous Owner field with what value in Issue Owner field. (This should happen on Form Load)

Now in you workflow you can compare Previous Owner and Site Owner. Make sure to set Previous Owner = Site Owner at the end of the workflow.

Comment: i though this could be achieved out of the box..

Comment: @johnG not as of SP 2013. But if you think logically workflow is designed to act on Current Item and not its previous version.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create another field in the list by the name of Previous Owner. Don't display it in the view. Set it to the same value to Owner when the item is created by a separate workflow that is run when a new item is created. Then create another workflow that only runs when the item is updated and compare the values of the Previous Owner and Owner. Send out the email if they are different and update the Previous Owner field value to Owner field value.

Comment: seems it is not straight forward as i thought ...